# how to teleport component in quasar(vue3) to the fullscreen?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-teleport

I followed [the teleport example](https://github.com/dannyconnell/vue-composition-api-course/blob/module-9/vue-composition-api-basics/src/views/ModalsView.vue)([youtube video](https://youtu.be/IEq4zVHhIMg?t=1335)) and want to set the component to the fullscreen.
However, the header and footer still show up when the component is teleported to `body` or `#q-app`.
The only difference between my code and the example code is I use quasar layout. Not sure if that matters.
here is my layout code:

```
<template>
  <q-layout view="hhh lpr fff">
    <q-header class="bg-white text-black" bordered reveal>
     ...
    </q-header>
    <q-page-container class="bg-grey-2">
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>

    <q-footer class="bg-white text-black bordered reveal>
    ....
    </q-footer>
</template>
```

here is my component

```
<template>
  <teleport to="#q-app">
    <div class="modal">
      <h1>This is a modal</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ipsa
        laboriosam vero natus ut rerum quaerat, saepe praesentium tempore et hic
        velit odio nemo minus labore quam ullam quod architecto?
      </p>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts"></script>

<style lang="scss">
.modal {
  background: beige;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up in CSS `z-index` higher than your header and footer components. For example `z-index: 100;`.

Comment: actually, I already tried that. but it doesn't work either

Comment: interesting. I tried a much larger value(10000) and it worked! Then I bisected the value and fount out the smallest workable z-index=2001.

Comment: @city You don't know what z-index is header footer, so you can try till it work on this component or lower index of header and footer.